# java error - Trying to convert jList.getSelectedValue() to int

Tags: java, jlist

When trying to convert the selected value from my jList into an int, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I have debugged the code as best I can and the problem seems to arise here `int id = Integer.parseInt(jList5.getSelectedValue());`. I've done similar things throughout the rest of the program without errors, I do not know what is wrong this time.

```
       import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
       import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


       if(jList5.getSelectedValue() != null){
           int id = Integer.parseInt(jList5.getSelectedValue());
           Main.oa.DeleteOrder(id);
       } else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR: No value selected");
       }


        DefaultListModel modelID = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.oa.getTop() ; i++) 
            modelID.addElement(Main.oa.currentOrders[i].getID());
        jList5.setModel(modelID);
```

The `DeleteOrder()` is meant to accept an int.

Comment: Based on the available code, `int id = Integer.parseInt(jList5.getSelectedValue());` would cause a compiler error, as `Integer#parseInt` expects a `String` value, but your `ListModel` clearly defines it's content as `Object` (`DefaultListModel<Object>`), which means that `JList#getSelectedValue` would be returning an `Object`

Comment: Thanks.So how do I convert an `Object` to `int`, or alternatively, how do I define my `ListModel` content as `int`?

Comment: Start by changing `new DefaultListModel<Object>()` to `new DefaultListModel<Integer>()` (I'm assuming that `Main.oa.currentOrders[i].getID()` is an `int` already). Then define `jList5` to support models of `Integers` (`jList5 = new JList<Intener>();`) then `getSelectedValue` will return an `Integer` and auto boxing will take care of the rest

Comment: That worked, thank you! I also tried doing             `modelID.addElement(Integer.toString(Main.oa.currentOrders[i].getID()));` when adding the elements to the list, which also did the trick. Is doing this not  a good idea?

Comment: No, not really, as Java will auto box `int` to `Integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your out-of-context code,

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(jList5.getSelectedValue());
```

would cause a compiler error

`Integer#parseInt` expects a `String` value, but your ListModel clearly defines it's content as `Object` (`DefaultListModel<Object>`), which means that `JList#getSelectedValue` would be returning an `Object`

Assuming that `Main.oa.currentOrders[i].getID()` returns an `int`, then in actual fact your actually trying to cast a `int` to a `String` to meet the needs of `Integer.parseInt` ... which is kind of weird.

Instead, get the model to match the requirements of the data

```
DefaultListModel<Integer> modelID = new DefaultListModel<Integer>();
```

And define the `JList` as supporting models on `Integer`s

```
jList5 = new JList<Integer>();
```

This way, `getSelectedValue` will return an `Integer` value

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DefaultListModel<Integer> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
                for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                    model.addElement(index);
                }
                JList<Integer> list = new JList<>(model);
                list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        deleteOrder(list.getSelectedValue());
                    }
                });
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteOrder(int id) {
        System.out.println("ID = " + id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `jList5.getSelectedValue()` is getting a string like `"asd"` instead of `"123"`
Try checking what is the value you are getting first before parsing it to int.